# C++ can't convert classes with templated argument in constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, polymorphism

The following has a very strange error:

In a header somewhere I have:

```
class WCameraPosition : public Widget3D
    {
    public:

        WCameraPosition(double scale = 1.0);
        WCameraPosition(const Matx33d &K, double scale = 1.0, const Color &color = Color::white());
        WCameraPosition(const Vec2d &fov, double scale = 1.0, const Color &color = Color::white());
        WCameraPosition(const Matx33d &K, InputArray image, double scale = 1.0, const Color &color = Color::white());
        WCameraPosition(const Vec2d &fov, InputArray image, double scale = 1.0, const Color &color = Color::white());
    };
class  Widget3D : public Widget
    {
    public:
        Widget3D() {}
    //...
}

typedef Matx<double, 3, 3> Matx33d;
```

For some reason the following compiles:

```
WCameraPosition camSymbol1(Matx33d(K));
WCameraPosition camSymbol2(1.0);
Widget w(camSymbol2);
```

But this does not:

```
WCameraPosition camSymbol1(Matx33d(K));
WCameraPosition camSymbol2(1.0);
Widget w(camSymbol1);
```

I get the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Widget3D::Widget3D(
WCameraPosition (&)(Matx33d))’
note: Widget3D::Widget3D(const Widget3D&)
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘WCameraPosition(Matx33d) 
{aka WCameraPosition(Matx<double, 3, 3>)}’ to 
‘const Widget3D&’
```

I'm utterly befuddled by this. It is as if a new templated type was created, but WCameraPosition and its superclasses don't even use templates. 
I need to pass camSymbol1 to functions taking Widget3D&. How do I fix this?

Comment: There are two many unknowns. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of [the most vexing parse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). The compiler thinks that this is a function declaration:

```
WCameraPosition camSymbol1(Matx33d(K));
```

Fix it by initializing your object using braces:

```
WCameraPosition camSymbol1{Matx33d(K)};
```

Comment: Ah! That worked! I see, so it has nothing to do with templates at all, just that I used a type name inside the parens. I'm still trying to work out how that could be a valid function declaration, but I get the idea.

Comment: @PaulFoster It's legal to surround variable names with parentheses. This is necessary when declaring things like function pointers (e.g. `void (*f)()`).

Comment: My next thought was "Why is this still allowed in c++11?" since I thought they got rid of the most vexing parse issues, but it turns out that this has the  obscure use that you can forward declare a function inside the scope of another function, so the parse has to remain legal.

Answer (score 0):

```
WCameraPosition camSymbol1(Matx33d(K));
```

Is a function declaration. You ran into the [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work).